Is Oauth integartion needed for PLD (The package level detail ) File Upload Process -UPS
UPS wants to integrate OAuth for calling their api as they are not going to support the access token from june. I generated token for that but is oauth integration necessary for PLD(The package level detail) File upload to ups.
I generated access token and refresh token also but not sure whether PDL upload api call needs oauth implemetation
